# Compile a PCL code example with QtCreator using CMakeLists file

Tags: windows-7, cmake, qt-creator, point-cloud-library

I'm trying to compile a *PCL* example with *QtCreator*, using a *CMakeLists.txt* file. The *FindPCL.cmake* file (got it from here: [Last of the attached files](http://dev.pointclouds.org/issues/148))  is in the same directory of the source files.

My *CMakeLists.txt* file is:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6 FATAL_ERROR)
project(pclcmake)
list(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "C:/CMake2.8/bin")
set(PCL_ROOT "E:/LIBRERIAS/PCL1.5.1")
set(PCL_DIR "E:/LIBRERIAS/PCL1.5.1/cmake")
find_package(PCL 1.5.1 REQUIRED COMPONENTS common octree io)
include_directories(${PCL_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(${PCL_LIBRARY_DIRS})
add_definitions(${PCL_DEFINITIONS})
add_executable(pcl_cmake main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(pcl_cmake ${PCL_COMMON_LIBRARIES} ${PCL_OCTREE_LIBRARIES} ${PCL_IO_LIBRARIES})
```

The code I'm trying to compile is this:

```
#include <pcl/io/pcd_io.h>
#include <pcl/point_types.h>

#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr cloud (new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>);

  if (pcl::io::loadPCDFile<pcl::PointXYZ> ("test_pcd.pcd", *cloud) == -1) //* load the file
  {
     std::cout << "Nope\n";
     return (-1);
  }
  std::cout << "Loaded " << cloud->width * cloud->height << " data points from test_pcd.pcd with the following fields: " << std::endl;
  for (size_t i = 0; i < cloud->points.size (); ++i)
     std::cout << "    " << cloud->points[i].x << " "    << cloud->points[i].y << " "    << cloud->points[i].z << std::endl;

  return (0);
}
```

I have also set the `PCL_DIR` var in my *CMakeLists.txt* point to the PCL install dir, as said in the PCL tutorial [Using PCL in your own project](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/using_pcl_find_pcl.php), at the bottom.

Finally, the error I get is:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:6 (find_package):
  By not providing "FindPCL.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "PCL", but
  CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "PCL" (requested
  version 1.5.1) with any of the following names:

    PCLConfig.cmake
    pcl-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "PCL" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set "PCL_DIR"
  to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "PCL" provides a
  separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been installed.
```

Any idea?
Thanks in advance.

PS: In the *CMakeLists* file, I point `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH` to the directory of the *CMake* binary. Is that right?

PS2: I'm using the MingW compiler.

PS3: The SO is Windows 7 64 bits.

Comment: Whoooooooooooops, forgot that!!. I'll edit the post!. Thanks!

Comment: Also, the compiler I'm using is MingW. I already added that info into the post.

Comment: Are you get the correct answer?

Comment: @YeYeahPing sorry?

Comment: I encountered this problem as well.

Comment: @YeYeahPing I didn't found a solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

You should set `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH` to the directory, which contains `FindPCL.cmake`. If this dir is standard CMake dir for modules (`share/cmake/Modules`), you don't need this at all.

Setting `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH` to the `bin/` dir is wrong, therefore.

Comment: Hi and thanks for your response. The `FindPCl.cmake` is in another dir (PCL1.5.1/cmake). So I have tried: `list(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "E:/LIBRERIAS/PCL1.5.1/cmake")`, it fails with the same error.
Then I tried changing the `list(APPEND ...)` line to `set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "E:/LIBRERIAS/PCL1.5.1/cmake")`, failed again. Also, commenting or uncommenting the `set(PCL_DIR...)` line doesn't matter, it fails yet again. :(

Comment: Try to `set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH E:/LIBRERIAS/PCL1.5.1/cmake)` before `find_package()` call.

Comment: Nope, same error. Should I remove the `list(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "E:/SITEGI/LIBRERIAS/PCL1.5.1/cmake")`, `set(PCL_ROOT "E:/SITEGI/LIBRERIAS/PCL1.5.1")
` or `set(PCL_DIR "E:/SITEGI/LIBRERIAS/PCL1.5.1/cmake")
` lines from the file first?.